# Otro cierre incorrecto por demasiado amplio : Referenciar un Control Java con un String

Tags: discusión, motivos-de-cierre

La pregunta es : [Referenciar un Control Java con un String [en espera]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59731/referenciar-un-control-java-con-un-string)

Está claro como el agua lo que pregunta. Lo está para quien entienda del tema. Dev Joel desde luego lo ha entendido y ha dado una respuesta que va en la dirección correcta.

Estos actos de moderación incorrecta dañan al sitio.

Comment: Lo que me llama la atención es el comentario: _"bucle for en java 148.000 resultados. ¿El que no sabes hacer exactamente?"_. No sería mejor que use los comentarios para pedir mayor información **si no entienden la pregunta** o no sabe que hace dicho código en VBA. Desde la [`revisión](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/59731/revisions) y los comentarios se logra entender lo que quiere el OP de la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que [revertir](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1669/revisions) la edición de @Rubén empobrece la publicación. Es norma habitual en [so], y creo interesante hacerlo aquí también, la de especificar la pregunta específica a la que nos referimos. De lo contrario, tendremos un millón de variantes del título "otro cierre", "cierre incorrecto", "no me gusta cómo cierran", etc. que no aportan valor alguno.

Comment: @fedorqui lo que no me gusta de la edición de Rubén es que ponga la etiqueta revisión-de-pregunta. Esa etiqueta es para "(...). Permite revisar el contenido para indicar correcciones antes de su publicación o revisar preguntas ya hechas. (...)". Evidentemente no aplica. Vi eso mal y ya no miré más; no gasto tiempo en rescatar malas ediciones. Respecto a especificar la pregunta específica. ¿Te refieres en el título o en el cuerpo? En el cuerpo ya lo puse y en el título no veo que sea costumbre hacerlo en [meta SOeng](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed).

Comment: Si te refieres al título me parece una buena sugerencia, la cual voy a seguir, gracias.

Comment: Sí, exacto, me refería al título de la pregunta. En [so] a mí me lo hicieron [una vez](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/282921/revisions) y me pareció que mejoraba mucho. Además, allí añaden la etiqueta [specific-question].